# Extracting Code Used in Wolfram Alpha Query Output

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

If I type `== moon texture map` into Mathematica it sends a query to Wolfram Alpha and gives me the following output:

[image]

A 3D sphere with a moon surface texture is exactly what I was hoping for, but how can I get the code that was used to produce the moon textured sphere so that I can use it in my own code? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `img = WolframAlpha[
  "moon surface map", {{"SurfaceMap:PlanetaryMoonData", 2}, 
   "Content"}]`

Comment: You can also get the same 3D graphic from `PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", "TexturedSurface"]` without invoking WolframAlpha. Evaluate `PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", "Properties"]` for a list of other properties that you can obtain through that command.

Comment: @MarcoB, that's a very nice way of doing it. Do you know if this can be combined with a ParametricPlot3D command?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question: what would be the parameter(s)?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the docs for `Texture[]`; there's a very relevant example there. You should be able to do something similar with the image you obtained from Alpha.

Comment: For example, could I combine `ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], Cos[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]` with your above code, so they show in the same plot.

Comment: @Guess who is it, brilliant examples in Texture[], just what I was looking for, thank you!